# Elasticsearch Geo Distance query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a list of places which have their latitude and longitude associated with them in the correct mapping of `geo_point`

I've also got a query successfully returning results based on geo distance which looks like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "30mi",
      "companies.locations": {
        "lat": "51.8801595",
        "lon": "0.577141"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_geo_distance": {
      "companies.locations": {
        "lat": "51.8801595",
        "lon": "0.577141"
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "unit": "mi",
      "mode": "min"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500
}
```

So this currently returns results within 30miles of the latitude and longitude provided. And this works fine.

I'm struggling with the next step, which I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction with.

Each place has a field called `distance` which is an integer. This is the maximum distance a place is willing to travel to a client. So if the distance is `20` (miles) but their latitude and longitude calculates as more than 20miles they should be excluded from the results.

The results come back like this:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "places",
        "_id": "AUtvK2OILrMWSKLclj9Z",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Chubby Company",
          "summary": "",
          "content": "",
          "locations": [
            {
              "lat": 51.8200763,
              "lon": 0.5264076
            }
          ],
          "address": [
            {
              "addr1": "xxxx",
              "addr2": "",
              "town": "MyTown",
              "county": "Essex",
              "postcode": "XX1 2XX",
              "tel1": "01111 111111",
              "tel2": "",
              "email": null
            }
          ],
          "website": "",
          "media": {
            "logo": "",
            "image": "",
            "video": ""
          },
          "product_ids": [
            "1",
            "3",
            "2"
          ],
          "distance": "20"
        },
        "sort": [
          0.031774582056958885
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `sort` object is distance in miles, so the result above is 0.03 miles from the client.

I'm trying to utilize this to check against the record using  result to exclude it from the results but this is where I'm falling down.

I've tried different combinations of this:

```
"script": {
  "script": "doc['distance'].value < doc['sort'].value"
}
```

which combined with the query looks like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "30mi",
      "companies.locations": {
        "lat": "51.8801595",
        "lon": "0.577141"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_geo_distance": {
      "companies.locations": {
        "lat": "51.8801595",
        "lon": "0.577141"
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "unit": "mi",
      "mode": "min"
    }
  },
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": "doc['distance'].value < doc['sort'].value"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500
}
```

But i get an error of:

> SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all
>   shards failed ... Parse Failure [No parser for element [filtered]

Any advice would be great.

**UPDATE**

Trying this also fails:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "30mi",
      "companies.locations": {
        "lat": "51.8801595",
        "lon": "0.577141"
      }
    },
    "script": {
      "script": "_source.distance < sort.value"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_geo_distance": {
      "companies.locations": {
        "lat": "51.8801595",
        "lon": "0.577141"
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "unit": "mi",
      "mode": "min"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500
}
```

with

> nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"script\"]; }]","status":400}

Comment: "this is the maximum distance a place is willing to travel to a client" - what sci-fi physics magic is this?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to have a conditional distance for each record that had this value stored in the data(searchRadius for me).  I ended up using the AndFilterBuilder and ScriptFilterBuilder classes in Java, so the AndFilterBuilder has an array of both a GeoDistanceFilterBuilder and a ScriptFilterBuilder.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "geo_distance": {
                                "location": [
                                    -104.99230194091797,
                                    39.74000930786133
                                ],
                                "distance": "3000mi"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "script": {
                                "script": "doc['location'].arcDistanceInMiles(39.74000930786133, -104.99230194091797) < doc['searchRadius'].value"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": "_source",
    "script_fields": {
        "distance": {
            "script": "doc['location'].distance(39.74000930786133, -104.99230194091797)"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_geo_distance": {
                "location": [
                    -104.99230194091797,
                    39.74000930786133
                ],
                "unit": "mi"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```